# Big integer in Forth?

Tags: biginteger, forth, gforth

I have developed a [big-integer system](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5hlt37gj46q0y3r/BigIntegerForth.txt?dl=0) (for numbers of dynamical length) in Forth (ANS-94), but it is too slow. Are there any fast systems available?

Also, any tip regarding the subject is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Forth Scientific Library](https://www.taygeta.com/fsl/scilib.html) includes [Arithmetic on big signed-magnitude numbers](https://www.taygeta.com/fsl/library/big.fth) module. Although, a test is required to see what implementation is faster. To use this module in SP-Forth some libraries should be included:

```
REQUIRE [IF]    lib/include/tools.f
REQUIRE M+      lib/include/double.f

S" big.fth" INCLUDED \ just for example
```

In any case, if Forth generates a code that performance is not sufficient (and algorithm is already optimized), any other implementation in form of dynamic library (DLL, SO) can be used.

Regarding performance, it is better to use dynamic memory (instead of dictionary space) for buffers in SP-Forth 4.21, since data-space and code-space are not separated.

Comment: I'm really interesting in other BigInt since mine is too slow. Unfortunately mine seems to be the only using stacks for big numbers so far, but the others might be faster, so I can borrow algorithms at least. BigIntegerForth use separately allocated memory areas for the big number stacks.

Comment: The code on Forth Scientific Library doesn't work properly on my system and I don't see why.

Comment: Yes, yes, I did that. Try yourselves big 1234567 big. 
1234567  Ok 
big 12345678 big. 
4295941036  Ok

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce the issue. Your testcase works for me.

Comment: Strange, since I use SP-Forth 4.20.

Comment: Yes, now it works for me to. I used your link this time and there may be some differences between the files. Now the algorithms are interesting, because some of mine are poor and made temporarily. But the system with big stacks are much better than some few variables. Thanks!